# How to make a QQuickWindow non resizeable?

Tags: qt, qml

Looks straightforward but I could not find a solution. There are no window flags for it besides the Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint. Found no properties or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a hack, but this one worked for me:

```cpp
connect(root_object_, &QQuickItem::widthChanged, this, [this]{
    setMinimumWidth(root_object_->width());
    setMaximumWidth(root_object_->width());
});
connect(root_object_, &QQuickItem::heightChanged, this, [this]{
    setMinimumHeight(root_object_->height());
    setMaximumHeight(root_object_->height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#initial-geometry) suggests (though it doesn't say so explicitly) that resize() results in a fixed size window.